# Issue with JS/jQuery function calling from different buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but how come I can't use the 2nd button for each call (based off the button ids)?

I tried to search for running multiple instances of function calls on google, but nothing relevant came up.

I'm planning on using this button a lot on a page I'm building, 10 or so instances.

```js
$(function(){
 $('#consoleLog').on('click', function(){
  var dataVar = $(this).attr('data-href');
  consoleLog(dataVar);
 });

 document.getElementById("consoleLog2").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var dataVar = $(this).attr('data-href');
  consoleLog(dataVar);
 });
});

function consoleLog(dataVar) {
 console.log(dataVar);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="consoleLog" type="button" data-href="This is a test.">Console Log</button>

<button class="btn btn-default" id="consoleLog" type="button" data-href="This is a test, again.">Console Log v1.2</button>

<button class="btn btn-default" id="consoleLog2" type="button" data-href="This is another test.">Console Log v2</button>

<button class="btn btn-default" id="consoleLog2" type="button" data-href="This is another test, again.">Console Log v2.2</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the same id in multiple elements. Id should be a unique attribute. Use it as a class and implement the event listener for the class.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.consoleLog').on('click', function(){
    var dataVar = $(this).attr('data-href');
    consoleLog(dataVar);
  });
  
  $('.consoleLog2').on('click', function(){
    var dataVar = $(this).attr('data-href');
    consoleLog(dataVar);
  });
});

function consoleLog(dataVar) {
   console.log(dataVar);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default consoleLog" id="consoleLog" type="button" data-href="This is a test.">Console Log</button>

<button class="btn btn-default consoleLog" id="consoleLog1" type="button" data-href="This is a test, again.">Console Log v1.2</button>

<button class="btn btn-default consoleLog2" id="consoleLog2" type="button" data-href="This is another test.">Console Log v2</button>

<button class="btn btn-default consoleLog2" id="consoleLog3" type="button" data-href="This is another test, again.">Console Log v2.2</button>
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know there was a difference like that between IDs and Classes.

Answer (score 2):

Try using additional classes instead of ids. Ids are meant to be used for one element.

```js
$(function(){
 $('.consoleLog').on('click', function(){
  var dataVar = $(this).attr('data-href');
  consoleLog(dataVar);
 });
   
});

function consoleLog(dataVar) {
 console.log(dataVar);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default consoleLog" type="button" data-href="This is a test.">Console Log</button>

<button class="btn btn-default consoleLog" type="button" data-href="This is a test, again.">Console Log v1.2</button>

<button class="btn btn-default consoleLog" type="button" data-href="This is another test.">Console Log v2</button>

<button class="btn btn-default consoleLog" type="button" data-href="This is another test, again.">Console Log v2.2</button>
```

I also don't understand why you have two consoleLog functions. Does this suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by just changing the function name that we call.